# Replace Fragment from OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm running into trouble. I have a Fragment with an onclicklistener. The fragment calls "ClickMe" which is in my Activity that hosts the fragment. However, in order for ClickMe to not error out, ClickMe has to be static. But, Clickme can't be static because then getFragmentManager errors out. Essentially I'm trying to create a game. A click will put a new fragment over the top of the old one (as you have to do the same thing 10 times in a row in my game. Here's the code:

Fragment:

```
text1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(loc1 == 10 || loc2 ==10){
            //Text if user wins
            BlankFragment.counter ++;
            BlankFragment.ClickMe(BlankFragment.counter);

            Log.i("Win: ", "Yay");
        }else{
            //Text if user loses

            Log.i("Lose: ", "Boo");
        }
    }
});
```

MainActivity:

```
public void ClickMe(int count){
Fragment newFragment;
counter = count;
if(counter > 5){
    newFragment = new g3by3Fragment();
}else{
    newFragment = new g3by3Fragment();
}

FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
transaction.commit();
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to preform `FragmentTransactions` from the `Activity`. You can just add well preform them from the `Fragment`. Your detour into the `Activity` through `ClickMe` is unnecessary. I know you probably do this because the logic of your game is in the `Activity` but that is not optimal. Let the `Fragments` themselves decide which `Fragment` comes next or implement a Singleton which takes care of your game logic.

Comment: Such a simple solution that I was over-thinking it. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm happy I could help you. If you think my answer is helpful please accept it by clicking on the check mark next to it. This indicates to other people that this answer helped you and it gives both of us a little reputation.

Comment: Implemented the code in the fragment and it works perfectly. I accepted your answer, thanks again!